# Multiple Topics in MQTT client(Esp32) to be sent to Raspberry Pi (MQTT broker)

Tags: c++

I am trying to send multiple messages from Esp32 to Raspberry Pi which is the MQTT broker itself but it always sends only one message and never sends the second message. Also, the Esp32 shows "Connection to MQTT failed" on the serial monitor. I am posting my code which is my approach, kindly tell me what mistake I am making. Thank you.

```
#include <HardwareSerial.h>
#include <PubSubClient.h> //Connect and publish data to the MQTT broker
#include <WiFi.h> //Enables Esp32 to connect to the local network(via WiFi)
#define RXD2 16
#define TXD2 17
//char myRcvChar;
//WiFi
const char* ssid = "Bilal-Asad-310";
const char* wifi_password = "31019309";
//MQTT
const char* mqtt_server = "192.168.0.106";
const char* message1_topic = "test/esp32/message1";
const char* message2_topic = "test/esp32/message2";
//const char* bending_topic = "exoskeleton/walking/bending";
//const char* streching_topic = "exoskeleton/walking/streching";
const char* mqtt_username = "bilal"; //MQTT username
const char* mqtt_password = "mqtt"; //MQTT password
const char* clientID = "client_esp32";

//Initialise the Wifi and MQTT Client objects
WiFiClient wifiClient;
//1883 is the listener port for the broker
PubSubClient client(mqtt_server,1883,wifiClient);


//Custom function to connect to the MQTT broker via WiFi
void connect_MQTT(){
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);

  //Connect to the WiFi
  WiFi.begin(ssid, wifi_password);

  //wait until the connection has been confirmed before continuing
  while(WiFi.status()!= WL_CONNECTED){
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  //Debugging-Output the IP Address of the ESP32
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");
  Serial.println("IP Address");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  //Connect to MQTT Broker
  //client.connect returns a boolean value to let us know if the connection was successful
  //if the connection is failing, make sure you are using the correct MQTT Username and Password
  if(client.connect(clientID,mqtt_username,mqtt_password)){
    Serial.println("Connected to MQTT Broker");
  }
  else{
      Serial.println("Connection to MQTT Broker failed...");
  }
}

void setup(){
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(115200);
  //Serial2.begin(115200, SERIAL_8N1, RXD2, TXD2);
 //char myRcvchar;


}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  connect_MQTT();
  Serial.setTimeout(1000);
  //Serial.println("Data Received: ");
  //Serial.println(Serial2.readStringUntil('\n'));

  const char* message1 = "EEG Sensor";
  const char* message2 = "EMG Sensor";
  Serial.println("Message1 Received: ");
  Serial.println(message1);
  Serial.println("Message2 Received: ");
  Serial.println(message2);
  //MQTT can only transmit strings
  String ms1 = "Mess: "+String((char*)message1);
  String ms2 = "Mess: "+String((char*)message2);
  
  //Publish to MQTT broker
  if(client.publish(message1_topic, String(message1).c_str())){
    Serial.println("Message1 sent");
  }
  //Again client.publish will return boolean value depending on whether it succeded or not.
  //if the message failed to send, try again, as the connection might have broken
  else{
    Serial.println("Message1 failed to send. Reconnecting to MQTT Broker and trying again");
    client.connect(clientID,mqtt_username,mqtt_password);
    delay(10); //This delay ensures that client.publish does not clash with client.connect call
    client.publish(message1_topic,String(message1).c_str());
  }
  if(client.publish(message2_topic, String(message2).c_str())){
    Serial.println("Message2 sent");
  }
  else{
    Serial.println("Message2 failed to send. Reconnecting to MQTT Broker and trying again");
    client.connect(clientID,mqtt_username,mqtt_password);
    delay(10); //This delay ensures that client.publish does not clash with client.connect call
    client.publish(message2_topic,String(message2).c_str());
  }
  //client.disconnect(); //disconnect from the MQTT broker
  //delay(1000*60); //print new values every 1 minutes
  client.loop();
}
```